# I need help wrapping my head around a scheme expression

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

```
(apply map list '((a b c) (1 2 3))) => ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
```

I can't really wrap my head around this expression. What is happening here?

Comment: Soon, you will memorize and remember "apply-map-list" as a famous Lisp idiom for transposing a 2D list-of-lists matrix.  I've been hearing rumors that Google, not satisfied with "map-reduce", is planning to roll out "apply-map-list" over its clusters in order to turn the Internet on its ear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand is what `map` does. `map` takes a function and one or more lists. `map` then calls that function on the first element of each list, and that becomes the first value in the list returned by `map`. `map` repeats this for the second element in each list, and so on until one of the lists runs out of elements. For example:

```
(map + '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) => (5 7 9)
```

`map` first calls `+` on the first argument of each list, 1 and 4, to get 5 as the first value in the resulting list. The other values are calculated in the same way.

`apply` works by taking a function, a bunch of values, and a list as its last argument. `apply` first appends all of its arguments besides the function to the list passed in as its last argument so that:

```
(apply map list '((a b c) (1 2 3)))
```

becomes

```
(apply map (list list '(a b c) '(1 2 3)))
```

`apply` then calls the function passed into it with each element of the list as a separate argument, so the above becomes:

```
(map list '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
```

`map` will call `list` on the first argument of each list and get `(a 1)` which becomes the first value in the resulting list. The same thing happens for the rest of the lists.

Answer (score 1):

`apply` is easy to handle as a purely textual transformation of your code, from

```
(apply map list '( (a b c)  (1 2 3) ))
```

to

```
(      map list   '(a b c) '(1 2 3)  )
```